# Passing an object from view to controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, controller

I want to add new message to database from my .jsp inputs via controller. I tried to just create new object of message in controller and put it in database and it works fine. But when I try to do it using inputs i receive error like this:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2]org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.doStartTag Neither   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'message' available as  request attribute
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'message' available as request attribute
```

My code:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
MessageService messageService;

@PostMapping("/messages/sendNewMessage")
public String sendNewMessage(@ModelAttribute("message") MessagesEntity tempMessage) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    tempMessage.setFromUsername(userService.getUser(auth.getName()));

    messageService.sendNewMessage(tempMessage);
    return "redirect:/messages";
}
}
```

JSP here

```
<form:form action="sendNewMessage" modelAttribute="message" method="POST">

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Username:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="toUsername" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="subject" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Content:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="content" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label></label></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send" class="save" /></td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using action url as `sendNewMessage` in jsp view but in the controller, it is `/messages/sendNewMessage`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad. I've tried many things before and forgot to change it. After the change, the problem is the same.

Comment: @PaulSmith 
I tried your code, just  with simple text element removing table attribute with input fields i.e  `<input type="text" name="toUsername">`  and other two. Everything just works fine with modelAttribute[** by correcting url**]. What I can suggest more is you can parse the table data  if you want to submit a table data or submit by ajax call. That would be much easier.

Comment: I think I know where the problem may be. "toUsername" actually is not a plain text, but it's User entity. Anyway I don't know how to get User entity by username in jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put MessagesEntity object in ModelAttribute.

Either define the ModelAttribute while loading the form page like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String messageForm(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("message", new MessagesEntity()); 
    return "messageFormPageName"; 
}
```

or Put below method in the controller which will be common for complete controller so ModelAttribute will be available always.

```
@ModelAttribute("message")
public MessagesEntity createModel() {
    return new MessagesEntity();
}
```